# ng-change for non input elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm binding `myCtrl`'s member `mydata` to DOM as below

```
<div id="{{myCtrl.mydata}}">I'll change if my id changes</div>
```

`mydata` is being fetched asynchronously.

```
$http.get('/mydata.json').success(function (data) {
    myCtrl.mydata = data;
    var mydiv=document.getElementById(data);    // this don't work 'coz the change -
    if(mydiv){                                  // is not yet reflected in DOM   
         mydiv.innerHTML="my new id is "+data;
    }
});
```

How to trigger a function after myCtrl.mydata is reflected in DOM. I just need a DOM ready event to hook on.

Comment: Why can't you use the success callback? you aren't trying to manipulate html in a controller are you?

Comment: hmm... it seems that's exactly what you're doing... Don't do that!!

Comment: Yup, definitely - this should be a directive.

Comment: @KevinB I need to do that!

Answer (score 2):

You need to watch for changes of your model, this is the best you can do to detect changes:

```
$scope.$watch('mydata', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        // mydata changed...
    }
});
```

Comment: Or prior triggering $digest on the scope.

Comment: This may be what I'm looking for. can you point me to a quick tut other than https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope ?

Comment: $watch triggers before newVal is bound to DOM! useless!!

Comment: Well it triggers whenever value changes. So yes, it will trigger for the first time.

Comment: Why do you want it to trigger exactly "after"?

Answer (score 0):

change your code to be like this:

```
$http.get('/mydata.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.mydata = data;
});
```

and your html

```
<div id="mydiv">{{mydata}}</div>
```

Anything you put in `$scope.mydata` will be reflected inside the div

Answer (score 0):

Don't manipulate html in controllers, you should instead simply interact with the data. The data-binding will change the html for you.

```
$http.get('/mydata.json').success(function (data) {
    if (data === "changed") {
        myCtrl.mydata = "rechanged";
    } else {
        myCtrl.mydata = data;
    }
});
```

---

If you ever find yourself trying to interact with html directly in angular, first try to avoid it, and if you can't you need a directive.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an Angular way of doing it. Its discussed here.
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/734